Prove that $\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{(a^2 + 5b^2)(b^2 + 5c^2)} \geq 2(a + b + c)^2.$

inequality

For all reals, prove that:
\begin{align*}
& ab(a+b)+ac(a+c)+bc(b+c)  \\
& \hspace{5mm} + 2\sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)(a^4+b^4+c^4-a^2b^2-a^2c^2-b^2c^2)} \\
& \hspace{15mm} \geq 2(a^3+b^3+c^3).
\end{align*}
My attempt
I have considered a few methods. One method is to square both sides and simplify. After doing so the remaining inequality to prove is
$$\sum_{\text{cyc}} \sqrt{(a^2 + 5b^2)(b^2 + 5c^2)} \geq 2(a + b + c)^2.$$
I am stuck at this point. Any help, or hints, would be appreciated.

This question needs to be refined to include a question or some phrase of asking for help or guidance.

@Leucippus
Thanks, I’ve edited it.

See this.

@CalvinLin  Thanks alot

It's an old problem of mine (here). The proof uses an identity
$$6(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca) = \sum (2a-b-c)^2.$$
